# What can I use instead of <input type="submit" /> in Html.BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Button I'm using has to have a background-image, but `<input type="submit">` can't have a background-image.

For instance, I can use Html.ActionLink with image:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add to Cart", "AddCart","Products", new { id = Model.product_id,},new {  @class = "**add-cart item_add"**  })
```

class = "add-cart item_add" doesn't work in input

What should I do? Thanks a lot...

Comment: Use a `<button type="submit" ...` and style it with a (say) `background: url('/image/xxx.png');`

Comment: okay, I understand, but I have one more question. Why doesn't @class = "add-cart item_add" work in input ? It works with Html.ActionLink

Comment: It does - but you have not shown your code for that (or what the css for `add-cart item_add` is) so impossible to tell what you done wrong

Comment: a.add-cart {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    padding: 0.4em 0.8em;
    font-size: 1.15em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
}
a.add-cart:hover {
 background: #73b6e1;
 transition: 0.5s all;
 -webkit-transition: 0.5s all;
 -o-transition: 0.5s all;
 -moz-transition: 0.5s all;
 -ms-transition: 0.5s all;
}  .item_add {
 color: #fff;
 border:none;
}

Comment: I have found out the mistake. I have to use <a href="#" class="add-cart item_add".

Comment: I have just fixed the problem, I deleted "a", so I mean it should be .add-cart

Answer (score 0):

Input button of type submit should be stylable; however, you can use `<button type="submit"` or `<input type="image"` for [image button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image).  For image button, set the src attribute; for button, add a `background-image: url("../images/something.png")` as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use a button and on the button's on click event, make a call (ajax if you need) to the server using javascript.
Your code would look smth like this:

```
<button id="yourBtnName" class="add-cart item_add">Submit</button>

<script>
$('#yourBtnName').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

   //do whatever you want to do on the button click event
});
</script>
```